# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

i got this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:849)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
```

the problem is that not all Android version get this error. For example Android 6 works well whereas Android 4.3 throws this error. Could somebody help me what to do?

my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'se.simbio.encryption:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: this is not related to your issue but why not simply defining your dependency with compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'?

Comment: How do you launch your program?

Comment: I tried but it has the same result. I build the apk and install it on the device

Comment: jsoup is in your classpath?

Comment: yes it works on Android 5 and 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I don´t know why but I had included the whole 'play-services:8.4.0'. Because of that I had to enable multiDexEnabled and with that I got this NoClassDefFoundError. So without multiDexEnabled everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try without adding this line `compile files('libs/jsoup-1.9.2.jar')` ? And send me a feedback ?

Comment: Unfortunately it has not helped

Comment: I guess that someone downvoted it because it should be a comment not an answer

Comment: I think that this could be an answer too...and I just can't comment everywhere now...I need less than 10 reputation...

Comment: hi i'm sorry it was not me who downvote. Many thanks for your ideas guys!

Comment: No problem, you found the solution you were searching, so that's good ^^